# How to parse continuous stream of text

Tags: .net, yacc, lex

I have the task to write an application that controls OpenVPN using the [management interface](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html), which is just a text stream.

I thought about using a lexer and parser generator like lex and yacc to do the job. But since there also are asynchronous lines beginning with ">", I don't know if that is even possible.

Should I just parse the text myself or can lex and yacc (actually, fslex and fsyacc, since I should use F#) deal with that sort of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably feasible. You can best handle the asynchronous lines by overruling `input` of the lexer and take those asynchronous lines out at the earliest stage. Should those lines be injected somehow into the steady stream of tokens or can/will they be handled separately? Injecting into the steady stream is going to be more difficult unless you have easy to detect points to inject them.

Comment: They will be handled separately.
I will accept your answer because it works! Taking out the asynchronous stuff before passing it to the lexer is indeed a good solution. Thank you!